# Should the [pipeline] be plugged?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

There is a tag [pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipeline) that currently has 1727 questions.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It is being used for a variety of different pipelines.

- Jenkins Pipelines
- BizTalk Pipelines
- PHP/Ubuntu
- Go
- R
- Scrapy

And that is just on the first few pages.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site??

Yes, most of them look to be on topic.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No, a more specific tag would be better.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No as per the answer to the first question.

---

There are some more specific tags

So should questions marked

- [Django & Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipeline%20django?mode=all) have their Pipeline tag be re-tagged to [django-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-pipeline)?
- [Jenkins & Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins%20pipeline?mode=all) or [Jenkins-plugins & Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-plugins%20pipeline?mode=all) have their Pipeline tag to be re-tagged to [jenkins-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-pipeline)?
- [BizTalk & Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biztalk%20pipeline?mode=all) have their Pipeline tag to be re-tagged to [biztalk-pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biztalk-pipelines)?
- [Scrapy & Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrapy%20pipeline?mode=all) have their Pipeline tag to be re-tagged to [scrapy-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrapy-pipeline)?

Some other pipeline tags

- [asset-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asset-pipeline) JavaScript / CSS
- [bitbucket-pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitbucket-pipelines) BitBucket CI system
- [amazon-data-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-data-pipeline)
- [integrated-pipeline-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integrated-pipeline-mode) seems to be ASP.Net
- [content-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-pipeline)  Usually invoked as part of an "XNA Content Project" (*.contentproj) in Visual Studio (or MSBuild).
- [pipelined-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipelined-function) Use the result of a PL/SQL routine as if it were a table.
- [custom-pipeline-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-pipeline-component) mainly Microsoft BizTalk or SSIS
- [build-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/build-pipeline) being used for a mix of things some should possible be [build-pipeline-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/build-pipeline-plugin) for the Jenkins plugin questions

and more

Comment: To be honest i don't see why we should split that tag to get like not even 200 questions on each. `django`, `jenkins`, ... will be fair enough.

Comment: Also not to be confused with `pipelining`, which is a CPU mechanism. That tag seems to have some irrelevant clutter too, though.

Comment: @Walfrat  Those other tags mentioned in my question already exist.  But it should be considered what to do with the other Pipeline questions that don't have a more specific tag.

Comment: Also it seems some questions confuse this with the IPC term "pipe".

Comment: Flush the [pipeline]

Comment: I have added this to some [tag:powershell] questions when the question and/or answer(s) depend heavily on powershell's specific pipeline behavior.

Comment: I am certain--_certain!_--that some of these burnination requests lately are _just_ so somebody can make a pun in the title...